# Consultar que un datetime sea del dia de hoy

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un datetime en mi base de datos pero quiero consultar que ese datetime tenga el dia de hoy.

Ej: Si tengo una fecha en el date time del dia de hoy me traiga ese pero si tengo con el dia de ayer no me la traiga.

lo que tengo hasta haora es esto:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
                $hoy = getdate();
                $hoy_i = $hoy['year']."-".$hoy['mon']."-"."0".$hoy['mday']." 00-01-00";
                $hoy_f = $hoy['year']."-".$hoy['mon']."-"."0".$hoy['mday']." 12-29-00";
                $query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE date BETWEEN '$hoy_i' AND '$hoy_f'";
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Horas, minutos y segundos los tienes que separar con `:` (`00:01:00` y  `12:29:00`). Si el desempeño no es una gran preocupación puede ser: `WHERE date(date) = current_date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción que podrías implementar es teniento en cuenta el día de hoy entre las 00:00:00 y las 23:59:59. Para ello recuerda que la notación de horas, minutos y segundos va separado de dos puntos (h:i:s) en MySQL.
Este sería un ejemplo para consultar los días de hoy:

```
$hoy_i = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00"); // Ej: 2021-09-10 00:00:00
$hoy_f = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59"); // Ej: 2021-09-10 23:59:59
$query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE date BETWEEN '". $hoy_i. "' AND '".$hoy_f."'";
// Esto muestra lo siguiente (importante la comilla simple que recoge la variable fecha y hora)
//SELECT * FROM task WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-09-10 00:00:00' AND '2021-09-10 23:59:59'
```

date() toma la fecha actual con el formato que le estableces, pero puedes fijar parte de ello como hacemos con las horas, minutos y segundos. PHP [date](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

Es una manera de simplificar el código y hacerlo más legible.

Comment: Me funciono pero para atraer la hora y la fecha pero al hacer el query me sale este error
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 AND 2021-09-09 12:59:59' at line 1` esto lo saque del **mysqli_error**

Comment: He editado el código. Si utilizas fecha y hora, al haber un espacio en medio, hay que "comillar" la variable para que la englobe totalmente. Prueba el código ahora

Comment: Me ha funcionado muchas gracias

Comment: Ha sido un placer.